# Enhancement for Access so it can be used on an Intranet

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

Is there a simple and easy to use product that will allow users to view/run Access DB queries on the web? We'd also like reports to be available too.

We have a large number of Access databases, many of which act as front ends to data pulled from other DB systems (Oracle and SQL Server mainly). Access allows our power users to construct queries and reports relatively easily, link in new tables and so on. But other users can't easily use those DBs without messy file shares and other network headaches.

In an ideal world we could deliver the output from queries and reports straight onto the web, but AFAIK that's not possible without writing bespoke code? I've seen that Sharepoint might solve our probs, but that's looking like a hammer for our particular nut.

Comment: One thing I could think about is using the Access 2010 Web Database feature, which I believe was designed as a next step migration of these kind of network-share hosted databases in order to address the IT management nightmares... of course this is only useful if you have Office 2010 / SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

If using Access 2010, Web Databases seems the best option.  However, they currently only work with SharePoint afaik.

In the future, they will work with Azure at least.

One to watch out for is LightSwitch.  Version 1 still in beta, so a long way to go before that proves its metal.  Or otherwise.

A third alternative is [Naked Objects for MVC](http://www.nakedobjects.net/home/index.shtml).  So long as you know how to build a domain model, Naked Objects will auto generate an ASP.NET MVC app that does what it sound like you want.

They have a couple of good videos highlighting what NO for MVC does and how to use it.